# How to average output of current sensor to get smooth output?

Tags: pwm, low-pass, current-sensing

I am using INA138 current sensor with 100Hz, PWM duty 5%, 8-bit resolution signal load is a resistor,

I getting  zero readings while actual current readings also appear,

**edited** -

**zero current sense output - this means when the current sensor detects OFF DUTY of duty cycle it gives zero volts on the output.**,
**the load is an LED**,
**controlling led brightness with a feedback loop,**

I need to remove this zero by adding a low pass filter to the output of the current sensor

my sampling rate 255, cycles per second,

**I need continuous measurement without going to zero, to make fast feedback control loop,**
I get actual current reading 5-10 times per second while other readings are zero.

reading - 4.2,0,0,0,0,4.2,0,0,0,0,....

I have doubt,

What if I add an RC low pass filter on the output of current sensor?

I made small stimulation  100Hz 3.3V square applied to 50Hz low filter, (not 5% duty)
[image]
I see output voltage has averaged to 1.8V

[image]

how to avoid reducing voltage while low pass filtering?

Comment: Try reading the data only when the PWM is in the ON condition. If the current sensor is being read by the *same* micro controller that generates the PWM, **synchronising** the current sensor read to the PWM ON should be possible.

Comment: *"I need continuous measurement without going to zero, to make fast feed back control loop"*. Once your readings are synchronised to read only when PWM is ON, It might not make sense to have a control loop operating at the same periodicity as the PWM. The control loop should run 5 or 10 times slower than the PWM frequency.

Comment: Can you give more information about your PWM+load setup and what parameter exactly the control system is controlling.

Comment: *"how to avoid reducing of voltage?"* What do you mean by that? The figure has a wave form which looks to be 3.5V peak and roughly 50% duty cycle. The output is expected to be around 1.7V.

Comment: @AJN i am using esp32 to generate pwm 100Hz and uses inbuilt adc at 255 adc sampling cycles, how to synchronize these two?

Comment: You stop usingPWM at 100Hz

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 i did not get,what you said

Comment: What are you trying to control? tolerance error? SNR?, response time?  What is 100 Hz used for?  What readings are Zero? meaning what?

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 I have updated

Comment: It seems this is a learning exercise to study why sampling a PWM controlled function is slow when there are much faster ways to do this. So what is your real purpose?  Verify your PWM is working?  A 1st order filter is only -6dB attenuation per octave, so there must be a spec for ripple , or delay or better filter type to reject aliasing above Nyquist rate.  These are tradeoffs to learn